# Convert python regex backreference to lower

Tags: python

I created function for replace string with dictionary,

```
def tolower(text):
    patterns = {
        "\[(.*?)\]": (r"[\1-123]").lower()
    }
    for key in patterns:
        text = re.sub(key, patterns[key], text)
    return text
print tolower("[IMG]UPPER[/IMG]")
```

But I want python backreference \1 convert the string to lower after replace.

So, I'm expecting the result like this :

```
[img-123]UPPER[/img-123]
```

Can someone please tell me how it's working with replacing regex backreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to using a callable as the replacement argument:

```
import re

def tolower(text):
    patterns = {
        "\[(.*?)\]": lambda m: '[{}-123]'.format(m.group(1).lower())
    }
    for key in patterns:
        text = re.sub(key, patterns[key], text)
    return text
print(tolower("[IMG]UPPER[/IMG]"))
# [img-123]UPPER[/img-123]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) that will allow you to do this, here is an example:

```
 def replaceLower(match):
     return '[' + match.group(1).lower() + '-123]'
```

To use it, instead of having each key map to a regular expression, map the key to a function that is called by `re.sub`:

```
def tolower(text):
    patterns = {
        "\[(.*?)\]": replaceLower
    }
    for key in patterns:
        text = re.sub(key, patterns[key], text)
    return text
```